# Why does Captain Marvel not age between the events of Captain Marvel and Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel, captain-marvel-2019, avengers-endgame

We know that Captain Marvel is going to cast on screen in *Avengers: Endgame* and there are no reports that she is going to be old in the movie.

She doesn't have a de-aging power according to the comics (that I know of).

So, how does she not age between 1990s and 2019?

Comment: It's all that flying around at relativistic speeds.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The bottom answer was "correct" at the time of the trailer, however, it is not necessarily the true answer now.

The true answer would appear to be because she was given Kree blood *and* her powers come from the Space Stone. Kree blood is said to have regenerative powers so this could have helped her not age.

> Another noteworthy trait is their highly potent regenerative capabilities. Their healing factor is considered to be so profound that S.H.I.E.L.D. attempted to use the G.H.'s blood to perform transfusions with mortally wounded, dying, or dead humans in order to resurrect them or cure them of terminal illnesses.
>
> <sub>[Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki, Kree](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Kree)</sub>

Carol also receives her powers from the Space Stone and so it is likely that the power of the Space Stone is what is stopping her from ageing.

[image: Carol absorbs the Space Stone's powers]

---

#### Because she is part Kree

This is stated in the [second official trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LHxvxdRnYc).

> Fury: And you're a Kree? A race of noble warriors?
>
> Carol: Heroes. Noble warrior heroes.

The Kree Supreme Intelligence later says the following:

> We made you one of us. So **you could live longer**, stronger, superior. You were reborn.

Comment: You may want to update this further once you've seen the movie, to talk about the effects of time dilation and its relationship to FTL travel. It may be worth its own answer, but I figure you should have the opportunity to cover it since it's certainly not given explicitly as a reason and is more boring than this reason.

Comment: @TylerH, there'd be no point in doing that because there's absolutely nothing in the movie regarding time dilation, so it would be pointless speculation given that there's a perfectly good reason already presented.

Comment: @KeithMorrison To the contrary, the MCU is a pseudo-realistic universe where any magic or cool phenomenon is basically just science we don't understand yet, and using a real scientific phenomenon to explain something in the movie that it definitely would apply to in real life, on top of the fact that the "perfectly good reason" is not one at all, but rather a lame, "because I said so" cop out, I'd say there's plenty of point.

Comment: @TylerH: There is no such thing as FTL travel in real world physics. Time dilation is part of relativity but that only deals with sub light speeds. You can in theory apply some of the equations to speeds that are faster than light but from memory anything that is travelling faster than light could never slow down to light speed or slower. So relativity's time dilation just doesn't seem to apply here. Nothing ever travels at near light speed in such a way that I consider time dilation to be relevant. That having been said if you think time dilation is relevant then make an answer saying so!

Comment: @Chris Luckily this is the MCU, not real world physics, so the two are only loosely coupled :-)