# How do Skrulls age?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019, spider-man-far-from-home, skrulls

Given *Captain Marvel* and the post-credits scene of *Spider-Man: Far from Home* we've observed

> Talos and Soren in both 1995 and 2024. And they appear the same.

Therefore they haven't aged in 29 years (or 24 years if they were Blipped).

Are Skrulls long-lived?  Or do they not appear to change as they age in their natural state, perhaps due to their shape-shifting capabilities?  Or am I just an ignorant speciesist who can't tell the difference?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202044/why-does-captain-marvel-not-age-between-the-events-of-captain-marvel-and-avenger?rq=1

Comment: There's no need to hide FFH behind spoiler tags especially considering you've tagged the question with it (and rightfully so).

Comment: How do Skrulls age? Very well, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

We don't have enough evidence to come up with a definitive answer on this but I would imagine that their life span is similar to that of a human. For an easy example look at Talos' daughter.

[image: Talos' daughter]

We see her in *Captain Marvel* which is set in 1995 yet we know she's been hiding on Mar-Vell's ship since at least 1989 because that is when Mar-Vell was assassinated by Yon-Rogg and she told them to hide there.

> **Soren:** It's okay. We didn't know what to do. Mar-Vell warned us not to send a signal for any reason or the Kree would find us.
>
> <sub>*Captain Marvel*</sub>

The girl would then have to be a bit older than that to account for being Soren getting pregnant and the girl being born. However, she doesn't appear to recognise Talos which would mean she was born when he'd already left meaning she can't be *that* old. This would mean she'd probably only be 6-8 years old and looking at her she appears to be a similar look to a human child of the same age. Therefore, they probably age at a similar rate to humans.

This is all assuming they've only been hiding out since around 1989 which we don't know for sure, if they've been there longer then obviously things change but I'm not aware of anything saying they were there longer than that.

Lastly, this does have real world precedent with people not appearing to age over time, I've met people like that through the years myself. For a couple of particularly relevant examples see Paul Rudd and Marisa Tomei. Paul is 50 years old yet if anything he looks younger than he did 15 years ago when filming *Friends*, it has even become a meme that he just doesn't age. Marisa herself is 54, 54!, despite not looking anywhere near that in any of the MCU films.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are shocked by Marisa Tomei:  I know lots of people who are in their 50s who look a similar age.  But, we seem to have been trained by Hollywood to expect characters in their 50s to look as though they are really in their 60s/70s - perhaps because we have so many 25-35 year old actors/actresses playing 18 year olds, and then aging the character?

Comment: @Chronocidal Personally I didn't know Marisa's age until recently, I always thought she was in her 30s by her looks alone.

Comment: That isn't necessarily proof their life timeline (if you will) is similar. Maybe they look like kids for 100 years, or something. We just don't know.

Comment: @Chipster sure, I’m not claiming it’s anything more than informed speculation.

Comment: Of course how they "really" look when it comes to beings that can shape shift, and change their dna, is always going to be a nebulous idea. Would they even project visible signs of age until they feel like it? Or would Talos always look like how he envisions himself looking, and that's why he doesn't appear to "change"?

Comment: @DariM:   Sure, but I think it's pretty clear the intent is that they really have some 'natural form'.   Don't they revert if knocked unconscious, etc?

Comment: He's impersonating Nick Fury, who can't be much younger than Samuel Jackson, who is 71. Skrulls could have a similar lifespan to humans and Talos is just enjoying the same spry old age Fury/Jackson does. (Personally, I imagine shapeshifters waking up every morning covered in sags and wrinkles, grunting with effort to make these indicators of age disappear. Each sleep time they relax and the wrinkles return. Each morning it gets harder to make them go away, until finally they end up in the Old Skrulls Home)

Answer (score 5):

#### Skrulls have a much longer lifespan than humans, living more than twice as long as the average human.

For instance, Talos, who appeared in *Secret Invasion* (2023 TV series), [S01E01 “Resurrection”](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Resurrection_(Secret_Invasion)), was revealed to be 136 years old. He stated that he was still young for his species, equivalent to a human under 40 years old, and that he had not experienced his midlife crisis yet.

> **Nick Fury:** Not bad for a 136-year-old.
>
> **Talos:** Well, you know, I'm not even 40 in human years. I haven't even gone on my midlife crisis shopping spree yet.

Comment: Or does that mean 136 years on Skrullos is roughly equal to 40 years on Earth?

Comment: @fez I don’t think that’s what Talos meant. Fury implied that Talos is old in Earth years. Then, Talos compared his age and lifespan to those of humans. He meant that he is still young for his species, equivalent to a human under 40, even though he is 136 in Earth years.

Comment: It always gets confusing when using "years" to refer to the life span of aliens 